# EditorFor checkbox always returning false

Tags: jquery, checkbox

HTML:

```
   <div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsFeatured)%>
</div>
<div id="IsFeatured" class="editor-field textbox">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsFeatured)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsFeatured)%>
```

jQuery:

```
var IsFeatured = $('#IsFeatured').is(':checked'); 
alert('IsFeatured= '+IsFeatured);
```

Howcome I always get false even when the checkbox is checked.

[this doesnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386453/checkbox1-checked-returns-false-vb-net)

[neither does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008441/checkbox-allways-returning-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `#IsFeatured` is a div not a checkbox try

```
var IsFeatured = $('#IsFeatured input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
```